# WiX: returning a value from exepackage

Tags: wix, return-value

I have been asked to add a function to an existing WiX package.
Specifically, I need to run a small c# application and return a single int back to WiX to conditionally control further actions.
I can see from [ExePackage help](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html) that there is an [ExitCode](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exitcode.html), but this is an enumeration of success, error, scheduleReboot or forceReboot.

I have googled quite a bit and I am wondering if I am missing the point. I can probably implement the C# process internally within WiX to get the user to provide the information I need, but the existing package already has custom ExePackages written in C# with a particular style, so I'd like to stay with that if I can. (The existing packages don't return any needed values)

Can I do this, or do I need to try and operate entirely within WiX?

For reference, one of the existing packages looks like this:

```xml
<ExePackage
    SourceFile="..."
    DisplayName="License Key"
    InstallSize="0"
    Permanent="yes"
    InstallCommand="/ignoreIfLicensed"
    RepairCommand="/ignore"
    UninstallCommand="/ignore"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference to `<ExePackage ...>` implies you want the condition to operate in a WIX bundle.  In this scenario I think your options are limited and you can only map the return value of an `ExePackage` to global behaviour like `forceReboot`.

Do you have any `<MsiPackage...>` references?  If you have, you could move the conditional behaviour inside each `<MsiPackage...>` using a Custom Action to call the exe and set a property.  The property can then be used as a condition in each `<component...>` you want to conditionally install.  See [Using a WiX custom action to set a property's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388795/using-a-wix-custom-action-to-set-a-propertys-value) for more information on custom actions setting properties.